# В чем заключается разница между new double[n] и new (double[n])?

Tags: c++

Читал документацию об операторе new на [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) и увидел следующий пример:

```
int n = 42;
auto p1 = new  double[n][5];  // OK
auto p2 = new (double[n][5]); // error: syntax (1) cannot be used for dynamic arrays
```

Хотелось бы узнать:

1. Чем отличается выделение памяти для p1 и p2.
2. Почему нельзя использовать non-const n во втором случае.

Comment: в стандарте написано, что в скобках должен быть строгий тип, без переменных. А если без скобок, то разрешается *первой* размерностью быть заданной переменной. `7.6.2.8 New` *почему - ???*

Comment: @AlexGlebe потому что иначе в скобках получается VLA-тип. Старые компиляторы так и ругались на такие попытки, "ISO C++ does not support variable-length array types"